# search funtionality using filter doesn't work the second time method in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, react-hooks

I am trying to implement search functionality using filter method in `React`. Below is the code:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { restaurantList } from "../constants";
import RestaurantCard from "./RestaurantCard";

function filterData(searchText, restaurants) {
  const searchedRestaurant = restaurants.filter((restaurant) =>
    restaurant.data.name.includes(searchText)
  );
  return searchedRestaurant;
}

const Body = () => {
  const [restaurants, setRestaurants] = useState(restaurantList);
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState("");
  return (
    <>
      <div className="search-container">
        <input
          type="text"
          className="search-input"
          placeholder="Search"
          value={searchText}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setSearchText(e.target.value);
          }}
        />
        <button
          className="search-btn"
          onClick={() => {
            const searchFilteredData = filterData(searchText, restaurants);
            setRestaurants(searchFilteredData);
          }}
        >
          Search
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="restaurant-list">
        {restaurants.map((fetchedData) => {
          return (
            <RestaurantCard {...fetchedData.data} key={fetchedData.data.id} />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Body;
```

But the problem I am facing is the search works the first time but doesn't work the second time because I am already updating the state with the filtered data.
Ex. The restaurant list has Dominos Pizza, KFC,... etc and I searched Pizza so the result has only one item Dominos Pizza and now when I search KFC, I get no results beacuse I had already updated the state for restaurantList.

How do i make it work correctly?

I tried to implement search funtionality in React using filter method and it should work everytime but it works only for the first time. Second time, I get no search results.

Comment: Could you pass `restaurantList` into `filterData` instead of `restaurants`?

Comment: @BenStephens would still work the same, have tried that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've said that you tried passing `restaurantList` into `filterData` instead of `restaurants`, but unless there's some details missing from your example it seems to work:

```js
const restaurantList = [
  { data: { id: 1, name: 'Taco Shack' } },
  { data: { id: 2, name: 'Salad Shed' } },
  { data: { id: 3, name: 'Bun Barn' } },
];

const RestaurantCard = ({ name }) => {
  return <div>{ name }</div>;
};

function filterData(searchText, restaurants) {
  const searchedRestaurant = restaurants.filter((restaurant) =>
    restaurant.data.name.includes(searchText)
  );
  return searchedRestaurant;
}

const Body = () => {
  const [restaurants, setRestaurants] = React.useState(restaurantList);
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = React.useState("");
  
  // original_functionality flag added to test using restaurants versus using restaurantList
  const [original_functionality, set_original_functionality] = React.useState(false);
  
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>
        <label>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={original_functionality}
            onChange={ (e) => set_original_functionality(event.target.checked) }
          /> Original functionality
        </label>
      </div>
      <div className="search-container">
        <input
          type="text"
          className="search-input"
          placeholder="Search"
          value={searchText}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setSearchText(e.target.value);
          }}
        />
        <button
          className="search-btn"
          onClick={() => {
            const searchFilteredData = filterData(
              searchText,
              original_functionality ? restaurants : restaurantList
            );
            setRestaurants(searchFilteredData);
          }}
        >
          Search
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="restaurant-list">
        {restaurants.map((fetchedData) => {
          return (
            <RestaurantCard {...fetchedData.data} key={fetchedData.data.id} />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app'));
root.render(<Body />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: This worked. there was Typo mistake. Thanks

Comment: But why doesn't it work the day before. I am just storing it in a local variable and then using it.

Comment: @AnishArya I don't think I know enough details of what you had yesterday to help with that (assuming that I've understood the question).

Comment: You were right, there was a typo mistake in my code in writing variable names. It worked later on.